# Finding common entries in different text file

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl. I have eight text files each with more than five thousand lines. I want to write a perl script to find entries (records) that are found in the first five files but not found the last three files. Let say the files are (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) so I want to get the entries that are found in `A` to `E` but not in `F` to `H`.

Can someone please advice on how to write a code to this job?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you need to:

1. Make a list of all the items in A-E (call it list 1)
2. Make another list of items in F-H (list 2)
3. Find all the items in 1 which are not in 2.

Instead of using two lists, you'd use two hashes.

```
# Two sets of files to be compared.
my @Set1 = qw(A B C D E);
my @Set2 = qw(F G H);

# Get all the items out of each set into hash references
my $items_in_set1 = get_items(@Set1);
my $items_in_set2 = get_items(@Set2);

my %unique_to_set1;
for my $item (keys %$items_in_set1) {
    # If an item in set 1 isn't in set 2, remember it.
    $unique_to_set1{$item}++ if !$items_in_set2->{$item};
}

# Print them out
print join "\n", keys %unique_to_set1;

sub get_items {
    my @files = @_;

    my %items;
    for my $file (@files) {
        open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
        while( my $item = <$fh>) {
            chomp $item;
            $items{$item}++;
        }
    }

    return \%items;
}
```

If its a one off, you can do it in shell.

```
cat A B C D E | sort | uniq > set1
cat F G H | sort | uniq > set2
comm -23 set1 set2
```

`cat A B C D E` smears the files together into one stream.  That's handed to `sort`, and then `uniq` which removes duplicates (`uniq` doesn't work well unless the lines are sorted).  The result is put into the file `set1`.  This is done again for the second set.  `comm` is then used on the two set files to compare them, showing only the lines which are unique to `set1`.